# Overwrite sender (From) when replying or making a new mail

Tags: outlook

We are looking for a way to overwrite the sender (From) when the user opens a new mail or replies to one. We found a tool (Bells&Whistles) which provides exactly what we need, unfortunatly they dont seem to reply to any form of communication so we started looking for an alternative.

Any suggestions, perhaps something we could code ourselves?

Comment: Why do you need to automatically overwrite the From field on the emails

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge and research:
For creating a new message, we can set another account as default and check the setting "**Always use the default account when composing new messages**" in Outlook, the field **`From`** is this account by default when we open a new email:

[image]

For **Reply** and **Forward** which is different from creating a new email, "*When we reply or forward a message, Outlook will always automatically select the account that we have received the message with. There is no way to change this other than to change the account manually before sending or to force Outlook to always prompt you for the sending account.*"(**[Always use my default account instead of automatically selecting it based on the current folder](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/disable-automatic-account-selection)**).

Comment: Does his mean that a second account should be added? In our case the default account should be a shared office365 box.

Comment: Yes, it needs the second mailbox profile. As far as I know, for Outlook side, we could only change the "From"  field manually currently. If I find any way to realize this feature, I will post it in my comment.